# Get Unique value from memcached memory

Tags: java, servlets, memcached

I am facing a weird problem.Actually I am putting the key value pair data in memcache memory.Now to keep the uniqueness of the key I append a unique random number to the key and then store it in the Memcache.But now the issue is what can i do retrieve the value from memcache because while retrieving i have only key not the appended unique id..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you adding a random number?

Comment: store the random number somewhere aswel

Comment: Hi BetaRide,
Actually the key is file name ,so for the uniqueness of key i am appending the random number to the key because there may exist multiple file with same name.